# Solr Highlighting: How to request multiple snippet lengths for the same field?

Tags: solr, highlighting

I am trying to find a way to request multiple snippets of different lengths for a single field. I know that this could be accomplished by issuing two separate queries or duplicating the field, but I want to avoid doubling the query load or index size. I'd also rather not resort to writing a custom snippet generator.

I am using Solr 4.0 and I thought perhaps the new [field aliasing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Field_alias) feature would be an ideal solution. However it appears that the highlighting component doesn't understand this new syntax. For instance the following request would ideally return two highlighted snippets: a short snippet and the full field:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?defType=edismax&q=foo&qf=content&fl=id&hl=true&hl.fl=content,snip:content&f.content.hl.fragsize=50000&f.snip.hl.fragsize=200&wt=json&indent=true
```

This results in something like the following:

```
"highlighting":{
"12345":{
  "content":{
    "snippet":["<em>foo</em> bar baz"]},
  "snip:content":{
    "snippet":null}},
```

From this I gather that the highlighter looks for the field named "snip:content" and fails. I tried a number of variations with the field alias specified in the fl, qf and [f.myalias.qf](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#Field_aliasing_.2BAC8_renaming) params, but to no avail. I've been pouring over JIRA issues, patches and source code but I can't determine what the proper syntax should be.

Does anyone have an ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can check on [hl.snippets](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.snippets) :-

> The maximum number of highlighted snippets to generate per field.
>   Note: it is possible for any number of snippets from zero to this
>   value to be generated. This parameter accepts per-field overrides.
>
> The default value is "1".

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. The hl.snippets parameter does enable multiple snippets, but only for a fixed length. How might you for example request two snippets of different lengths for a given field?